# how to create a form with a submit button and call a json webservice?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Hi i have a webservice that output data with json format. I need to create a basic form with one field named: SKU and a submit button.

After client clicks Submit button, it should call the webservice passing tru a variable for example:

http://wsURL:8090/ConsultaTarjetas/ExistenciaProd/ExistenciaProd.php?token=abcbdefgh123456789&reference=$SKU, this is the variable that came from wordpress form field named SKU

and shows a json results like:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "id": "22237897",
  "producto": "CAMISA MC OCEAN PACIFIC NAVY",
  "tallas": [
    "XS ",
    "S ",
    "M ",
    "L ",
    "XL ",
    "XXL",
    "3XL",
    "4XL",
    "1X ",
    "2XL"
  ],
  "sucursales": [
    {
      "nombre": "ALBROOK",
      "numtienda": "8.0",
      "numbodega": "0102",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "LOS PUEBLOS",
      "numtienda": "5.0",
      "numbodega": "0105",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "1",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "CHITRE MEN",
      "numtienda": "16.0",
      "numbodega": "0106",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "0",
        "2",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "TERRONAL",
      "numtienda": "14.0",
      "numbodega": "0908",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "2",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "DAVID",
      "numtienda": "9.0",
      "numbodega": "0909",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "2",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "COSTAVERDE MEN",
      "numtienda": "22.0",
      "numbodega": "0204",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "2",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "CAROLINA 2",
      "numtienda": "21.0",
      "numbodega": "0111",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "2",
        "2",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "CENTENNIAL",
      "numtienda": "25.0",
      "numbodega": "0112",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "SANTIAGO MALL",
      "numtienda": "26.0",
      "numbodega": "0113",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "2",
        "2",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "PENONOME BOULEVARD",
      "numtienda": "30.0",
      "numbodega": "0117",
      "precio": "24.989999999999998",
      "existencia": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "2",
        "2",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and i need to construct or show a table with that json, if result is False and fails, should show a error msg

at the end table should look like this:

[image]
thank you

Comment: What have you created so far? Where did you get stuck? We're not likely to just write your code to spec, but I'm sure you'd get help if you showed some effort and research and code

Comment: any way to achieve this with pure wordpress? or its better to create a basic php file outside and insert is as iframe?

Comment: i would get the response through ajax, build a table in js and append to the body. I don't see the need to get php or iframes involved so far